# Perf does not display call graph properly on Android

Tags: android, linux, profiling, perf

I am trying to use `perf` to profile my Android application.

With help of [fplutil](https://google.github.io/fplutil/android_ndk_perf.html%20fplutil) project I managed to install perf on Android device, run `perf record` and then `perf report` on host machine.

Usually when I run `perf report -g` I expect to see call graph similar to this one:

```
47.91%    a.out  a.out              [.] f5()
          |
          --- f5()
             |
             |--53.82%-- f4()
             |          |
             |          |--56.16%-- f3()
             |          |          |
             |          |          |--49.14%-- f2()
             |          |          |          |
             |          |          |          |--52.92%-- f1()
             |          |          |          |          a()
             |          |          |          |          main
             |          |          |          |          __libc_start_main
             |          |          |          |
             |          |          |           --47.08%-- a()
             |          |          |                     main
             |          |          |                     __libc_start_main
```

However when I execute `perf report` for data collected on Android device I do not see proper call graph, like if stack is not unwinding properly:

```
4.98%  app_name  my_lib.so  [.] void quat_apply<double>(double*, double const*, double const*, int, double)
            |                                                                                              
            --- 0xbee75fe4                                                                                 

            |                                                                                              
            --- 0xbee760c4                                                                                 

            |                                                                                              
            --- 0xbee75c0c
```

What should I do to replace these hex addresses with function names?

I am already building my code with `-g` and `-fno-omit-frame-pointer`, am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bingo!

```
-mapcs-frame
```

> Generate a stack frame that is compliant with the ARM Procedure Call
>   Standard for all functions, even if this is not strictly necessary for
>   correct execution of the code. Specifying -fomit-frame-pointer with
>   this option causes the stack frames not to be generated for leaf
>   functions. The default is -mno-apcs-frame. This option is deprecated.

Although option is marked as deprecated, it fixed call graph for me.

Comment: Luckily I saw someone else also tried to use perf for Android. I've met several problems. If you could give me some suggestion, that would be very appreciated.

Comment: Basically I gave up with perf, seems like it does not work anywhere but on  a couple of devices that are listed in fplutil source code.
Now I profile C++ Android applications with a variation of "poor man profiler". You probably know the idea: you start your algorithm and periodically stop execution using debugger and see what code is executed. It is very cumbersome to do this manually, but you can automate the process. I wrote some scripts to do this, although I am not yet ready to share them. If you're interested in this approach I can probably help you. At least it works.

Comment: Thanks. I guess my purpose is a little different from yours. What I hope to do is to automatically capture Android app's native calls' execution sequences, without source code. The best way, I think is to do this from CPU side, like branch tracing, which is Intel CPU's design originally. But on my Nexus 5x, I failed to test it. So that I turned to perf for another way to go. Android NDK perf was out of support. Google brought in simpleperf instead. And it's been in continuous development. But so far simpleperf could not fulfill my needs completely. I'm still trying and kind of stuck.